# Block particular path on ingress-nginx Loadbalancer

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have many domain pointing to Ingress Controller IP. I want to block /particular-path for all the domains/sites. Is there a way to do this.
I can use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |`  for each site. But looking for way to do for all sites/domains/Ingress resource at once.

Controller used: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/

Comment: In order to provide you solution we need to have a little bit more details from you to help us understand your goal. The purpose of ingress is to allow traffic, not to block so if you want to block some specific path why even mentioning it?  Providing your ingress configuration manifest would also give us clearer picture of your use case. Can we assume that you are using nginx ingress controller?  If yes, ten which one (nginxinc or nginx community).

Comment: @thomas Many sites/domains points to the ingress controller. I want to block path `/admin-access` for all the sites/domains/subdomains. Is there a way to do it on controller it self?

Comment: There might be a way but I still need to test it. Once done I`ll post my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

**1. First one is with using `server-snippet` annotation:**

> Using the annotation  `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet`  it
> is possible to add custom configuration in the server configuration
> block.

Here is my manifest for the ingress object:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
          location ~* /admin-access {
              deny all;
              return 403;
            }
spec:
  rules:
  - host: domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: web 
          servicePort: 80
```

Please note that using  [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet) approach :

> This annotation can be used only once per host.

---

**2. Second one is with usage of [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#configmaps) and [Server-snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#server-snippet):**

What you have to do is to locate your `configMap`:

```
 kubectl get pod <nginx-ingress-controller>  -o yaml
```

This is located the container `args`:

```yaml
  spec:
   containers:
   - args:
     -  /nginx-ingress-controller
     - configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-loadbalancer-conf
```

And then just edit it and place add the `server-snippet` part:

```yaml
   apiVersion: v1 
   data:  
   server-snippet:  |
   location /admin-access {
   deny  all;
    }
```

This approach allows you to define restricted location globally for all host defined in Ingress resource.

---

Please note that with usage of `server-snippet` the path that you are blocking cannot be defined in ingress resource object. There is however another way with `location-snippet` via `ConfigMap`:

```yaml
location ~* "^/web/admin { 
        deny all; 
        }
```

With this for every existing path in ingress object there will be ingress rule but it will be blocked for specific uri (In the example above it be be blocked when `admin` will appear after `web`). All of the other uri will be passed through.

---

**3. Here`s a test:**

```sh
➜  curl -H "Host: domain.com"  172.17.0.4/test             
...
 "path": "/test",
 "headers": {
...
 },
 "method": "GET",
 "body": "",
 "fresh": false,
 "hostname": "domain.com",
 "ip": "172.17.0.1",
 "ips": [
   "172.17.0.1"
 ],
 "protocol": "http",
 "query": {},
 "subdomains": [],
 "xhr": false,
 "os": {
   "hostname": "web-6b686fdc7d-4pxt9"
...
```

And here is a test with a path that has been denied:

```html
➜  curl -H "Host: domain.com"  172.17.0.4/admin-access

<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.19.0</center>
</body>
</html>

➜  curl -H "Host: domain.com"  172.17.0.4/admin-access/test
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.19.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Additional information: [Deprecated  APIs  Removed  In  1.16](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/).  Here’s What  You  Need  To  Know:

> The v1.22 release will stop serving the following deprecated API
> versions in favor of newer and more stable API versions:
>
> Ingress  in the extensions/v1beta1 API version will no longer be
> served

Comment: Thank you. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot block specific paths. What you can do is point the path of the host inside your ingress to a default backedn application that says 404 default backedn for example.

Answer (score 0):

you can apply it using the ingress annotation

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: channel-dev
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "27.110.30.45, 68.50.85.421"
  name: dev-ingress
  namespace: development
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hooks.dev.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /incoming/message/
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - hooks.dev.example.com
    secretName: channel-dev
```

path `https://hooks.dev.example.com/incoming/message/` will be only accessible from mentioned IPs other users will get **403** error and wont be able to access the URL.

just add this annotation in ingress

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range
```