# Block Hosts In ingress of kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a website hosted on GCP Kubernetes.
Someone has added a DNS entry against the website.

Is it possible to block all the websites, except for the application's URL?

Comment: Have you considered using the whitelisting feature of Ingress described here: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/87d1b8bbf28265386b339e65d8943d8c3f8582ed/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#whitelist-source-range?

Comment: We are getting a lot of traffic from different IP addresses. 
If someone has added a DNS entry that all the traffic coming to SITE A, will come to our SITE B. This way we are getting traffic from everywhere. Is there a way to block traffic coming from SITE A . 
Our site is also public, therefore we can't whitelist a specific IP range.

Comment: Have you seen this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65147557/block-particular-path-on-ingress-nginx-loadbalancer?